# Getting 404 on subrouting

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops

When i hard reload "https://xyz.co/inflow" , getting "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." error with 404 status

My project is setup with vite configs and azure devops service's

Comment: You should configure your server to redirect every route to index.html, because when you type ..../inflow it tries to find a file inflow.html which doesn't exists. Client side Reat handle everything from index.html file.

Comment: if we redirect with click actions then it's working ,

Comment: Hi there, Glad to know the site is working now. Could you please share your scenario and answer to solve this issue? Thx

Comment: @RaviKevadiya, Yes when you click its working, but when you refresh is another thing.. Because the browser is trying to access the route ex. .../inflow as i said in previous comment. Do you use azure `web.config` file ?